# Wordpress Multisite - List blogs of a user with pagination

Tags: wordpress, multisite

How can i list all the blogs of a particular user with the usage of pagination in wordpress multisite instance?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a small Gist](https://gist.github.com/JudeRosario/b26152b7acd8c9a74e4f), I wrote for you. You may need to tweak it a bit depending on your exact use case, but it does what you asked for. The pagination bit depends on exactly how you want it set up. [Here is an excellent read](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31431/how-to-paginate-the-get-users-function) . Also take a look at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) for more info. Hope that helps.